# How can I remove <br> and </br> tags from items in a list with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, web-scraping

The Html I'm scraping from:

```
<tr>
    <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffff99">
        <font size="2">
            <a href="some/link.htm">
                <b>SomeStuff</b>
            </a>
        </font>
    </td>
</tr>
</tr>
    <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffff99">
        <font size="2">
            <a href="some/link2.htm">
                <b>SomeMoreStuff</b>
            </a>
        </font>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How I'm scraping the information:

```
my_list = []
for i in soup.find_all('a',href=re.compile('some/link')):
    my_list.append(str(i.find('b')))
    my_list.append(i['href'])
```

I need to remove the HTML tags from elements in a list.
 However, when I create the loop it doesn't save any changes in the list. My list looks something like this:

```
my_list = ['<br>SomeStuff</br>','some/link.htm',
           '<br>SomeMoreStuf</br>', 'some/link2.htm',
           '<br>EvenMoreStuff</br>', 'some/link3.htm']
```

I've tried this:

```
for i in my_list:
    i = i.replace('<br>','')
    i = i.replace('</br>','')
```

And I've tried this:

```
for i in my_list:
    if '<br>' in i:
        i = i.replace('<br>','')
    if '</br> in i:    
        i = i.replace('</br>','')
```

None of this is making any change in the original list. I can print out the corrections I want by not storing the changes in anything:

```
for i in my_list:
    i.replace('<br>','')
```

However I need the change to be saved in the list.

Comment: You need to either (a create a new list and append your modified strings to that new list, (b use a list comprehension, or (c modify your original list by indexing it.

Comment: Actually you should post all your question from the beginning!  There is a much easier way to do it rather than remove the tags in the list.

Comment: Please see my answer for more info.

Answer (score 2):

All of the solutions work, you're just forgetting to update the list.

```
for i, element in enumerate(my_list):
    element = element.replace('<br>','')
    element = element.replace('</br>','')
    my_list[i] = element
```

Now printing `my_list` outputs:

> ['SomeStuff', 'some/link.htm', 'SomeMoreStuf', 'some/link2.htm', 'EvenMoreStuff', 'some/link3.htm']

You can also use a list comprehension, which will yield the same result:

```
my_list = [i.replace('<br>', '').replace('</br>', '') for i in my_list]
```

Comment: I've tried both of these and there is no error but the list doesn't change whatsoever.

Comment: Try either the for loop or the list comprehension and immediately after do `print(my_list)`. I can assure you, that it will have changed the list, reflecting what I wrote mine outputs.

Comment: Nope, If I could add a screenshot I would show you.

Comment: so If I create my own list and try it it works, but for the one I scraped it doesn't work... strange.

Comment: Include in your question how you scrape it, then I'll look into it.

Comment: The html you added doesn't contain any `<br>` instead it has `<b>`. Thus you just need to change `replace('<br>', '')` into `replace('<b>', '')`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If all the string only have tags in the beginning and end of the string, you can slice the string to remove them.  Try the codes below:

```
for lst in my_list:
    if '<br>' in lst:
        my_list.append(lst[4:-5])
        my_list.remove(lst)
```

Edits:

There is a more pythonic way to do it from @Vallentin's answer:

```
for i, lst in enumerate(my_list):
      if '<br>' in lst:
          my_list[i] = lst[4:-5]
```

Edits:

Actually you don't need to convert your result into string from the beginning. For this codes:

```
str(i.find('b'))
```

Please try

either

```
i.get_text()
```

or

```
i.b.get_text()
```

I think one of them should directly give you the content of your data.  So you do not need to remove the tags after this.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up solving the problem by writing the two elements into an excel file and then using 'find and replace' in excel!

Comment: I suggest you try my method, use the built-in method of .get_text() from beautifulsoup.  This will make you life much easier.

Comment: For some reason it kept returning a 'None type object just not have attribute text' error.